# Keycloak server behind Jetty reverse proxy

Tags: java, keycloak, embedded-jetty

I have embedded Jetty running on port 7000. Also, I have a keycloak server running on same machine on port 8100.
My all clients access goes via Jetty i.e. localhost:7000. So, I have put keycloak as reverse proxy on Jetty i.e localhost:7000/keycloak/auth will redirect to localhost:8100/auth. It is hitting correctly.

Now, there is KeycloakInstalled client to authenticate the user. I have provided auth-url as http://localhost:7000/keycloak/auth. When I run this client, it correctly authenticate the user, but when retruning the token, it gives out the exception that auth-url (localhost:7000/keycloak/auth) given to it does not match the url from keycloak sever (localhost:8100/auth).

I tried out doing following also:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/1.9/server_installation_guide/topics/clustering/load-balancer.html
But, I am unable to generate X-Forward headers from Jetty.

Am I doing any basic thing wrong here?
Any pointers here would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Anyone can help me here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I workaround it by mapping http://localhost:7000/auth (not localhost:7000/keycloak/auth) to http://localhost:8100/auth via Jetty reverse proxy. It worked perfectly.
P.S. I also need to add proxy-address-forwarding="true" in keycloak standalone.xml